# How to calculate probability for odds in favor for given problem

Tags: probability

If you are given odds 7 to 8 in favor of winning a bet, what is the probability of winning the bet?
Solve for x:  7 over x

Answer : 7/15 or 8/15 ?

Comment: The answer is $7/15$

Comment: As is, this is a [problem statement](http://goo.gl/mLWc8) (see also [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9180/272831)). Please note that [good questions](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) usually involve full thoughts, and full thoughts come in the form of full paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have chances $7:8$, then your chances of winning is: $\frac{7}{7+8} = \boxed{\frac{7}{15}}$
I'm not sure what you mean by "Solve for x" as the following information is an expression, but the answer would be $\frac{7}{15}$

Comment: You're welcome :D

Comment: Note that in horse racing, if you are given odds $7:8$ on an event then the implied probability of winning is ${8 \over 15}$.